# Youtube - Adding a comment in response to a video

Tags: php, youtube, comments

I want to post comment to respons of some YOUTUBE video. I am using PHP. 
Can anyone help me out this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the api see

http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments.html

To add a comment to a video, send an HTTP POST request to the URL identified in the  tag that appears inside the  tag. The actual comment that you are submitting appears as the value of the  tag in the XML that constitutes the body of the POST request.

The sample XML API request below demonstrates how to add a comment to a video.

```
POST /feeds/api/videos/VIDEO_ID/comments HTTP/1.1
Host: gdata.youtube.com
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Content-Length: CONTENT_LENGTH
Authorization: AuthSub token="AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN"
GData-Version: 2
X-GData-Key: key=DEVELOPER_KEY

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
    xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
  <content>This is a crazy video.</content>
</entry>
```

Comment: I see this API. I am not sure how to call this.. Any approach to write the coad please?

Comment: if you using zend this link explain how to call the api http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.youtube.html

Comment: if not look on this link how to work with php : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/

Comment: I think I might have stumbled onto this API at a time when they are going from v2 to v3 of the youtube API - at least as far as comments are concerned. I am trying to get a POST via Angular (front end js client) working - I am getting a (403) invalid developer key returned. Its a shame there isn't a mailing list for the youtube API.

You can test it live here - just try to add a comment under the main video - http://www.gamerdj.net.gridhosted.co.uk/videos.html?#/

The header is supposed to be set with bearer and token as provided and verified in a previous step.

what is content length ?